# pgf-pie - Show absolute values instead of percentage

Tags: formatting, pgf-pie

I want to make a pie chart with `pgf-pie` that shows not the percentage inside the pie but the absolute values. For example 15 males and 3 females in my example below. Is this possible with `pgf-pie`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pie[rotate = 180,
        color = {orange!40!white, orange!80!white}]
    {27.78/females, 72.22/males}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the option `sum = auto` (or `sum = <some value>`) the package will automatically remove the `\%` after the number (actually the package sets `after number = \%` when `sum = 100`, the default):

> [image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pie[rotate = 180, sum = auto,
        color = {orange!40!white, orange!80!white}]
    {27.78/females, 72.22/males}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```